# Webextension - Insert HTML file content in web page content

Tags: javascript, html, file, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm starting to port a script to a Firefox WebExtension. I'd like to insert into the currently displayed web page some HTML content, that I would like to store into a separate "local" .html file (so I don't have to rewrite it into an "impossible to debug" javascript variable, with all the special characters that comes with this kind of rewrite).

Is this possible, and if it is, how can I achieve loading the .html file content into a variable that I can reuse in the code to insert its content in the code ?

As a comparison, I think about the include statement in PHP that does about what I'd want to do here into the Webextension.

Comment: If you use a template literal, i.e. `\`<html>here</html>\`` you won't have to mess around with special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

- You can create the local HTML file, then read it with `new FileReader()` or `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` (probably the easiest) then convert to DOM with `new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html')`
- You can also keep the HTML in a string in the js file and then convert to DOM with `new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html')`
- **I have NOT tested this** (I never use bg HTML). You add a `background.html` and load `background.js` from it. Then having your DOM there, you can get it from bg script

However, if you want to programmatically inject the DOM, all above methods require `tabs.executeScript()` which requires strings and then it has to be converted to DOM in content.

PS. I would advise not using `innerHTML` (or JQuery `.html()`) for string to DOM conversion.